# Can I use a policy to enforce logging on Azure AD?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-active-directory, azure-policy

Can I use a policy to enforce logging on Azure AD?

Trying to look for an option to enforce logging for Azure Active Directory using Azure Policy.
I know there are many policies that can be used for this but I am trying to find how it would look like for Azure AD

Comment: Where you are trying to login with Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot because there is no ARM templates available for Azure AD (aka. Entra ID).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.aad/allversions

See different alternatives here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/monitoring-health/howto-access-activity-logs